# How to know when \Registry\Machine\Software key is loaded?

Tags: windows, registry, kernel, driver, internals

I want to access \Registry\Machine\Software key from a driver. The driver is loaded prior to the registry key. Do I have to poll the key availability? Or there is something I can wait for?

Comment: The problem is solved by polling for the key availability in the thread. It is pity that there is no event to wait for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourDriver\Parameters ?

I'm sure this question has been asked on the OSR mailing list several times, you can probably find more info [there](http://www.osronline.com/showlists.cfm?list=ntdev), but AFAIK, there is no event you can wait for.

Comment: The problem is that I need \Registry\Machine\Software (I'm not using it for my own parameters). Thanks for your reply. I just wanted to be sure that there is no better way instead of polling.